# Infer generic type in property (like in a function) for proper type checking

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I am trying to have the compiler infer and check types in a generic property.
In particular i have:

```
type Args<T, O extends object> = {
    instance: O,
    key: { [K in keyof O]: T extends O[K] ? K : never }[keyof O]
};

class C<T> {
    public fn<O extends object>(args: Args<T, O>): void { }
}
```

`Args` is a object and one of its keys `k`, such that something of type `T` can be assigned to `k`.
The class can be used like:

```
type Test = { a: string, b: number };
let test: Test = { a: "", b: 2 };
let c = new C<string>();

c.fn({ instance: test, key: "a" }); // works, as expected
c.fn({ instance: test, key: "b" }); // error, as expected
```

This is nice because the type parameter `O` is inferred, the type of `key` is checked and all possibilities for `key` are suggested when typing.

Now i want to use a `Args` object that can be used with `C<T>.fn` as a property in some other classes (for injection purposes), where the type of `O` is not known yet.
However type checking fails with `any`:

```
interface I<T> {
    args: Args<T, any>;
}

let i: I<string>;
i = { args: { instance: test, key: "b" } }; // no error
```

I tried to used a lambda instead:

```
interface I2<T> {
    args: <O extends object>() => Args<T, O>;
}

let i2: I2<string>;
i2 = { args: () => ({ instance: test, key: "a" }) }; //Type 'Test' is not assignable to type 'O'. ???
c.fn(i.args);
```

I do not understand why the type error occurs.

**How can you ensure types are inferred and checked for a property of an interface like it works for a generic function?**

Comment: You will need a function for its inference behavior. If you use `any` you don't get any type checks, and your lambda attempt fails because `O` is a generic type parameter to `args` so it's the caller who decides what `O` is not the implementation.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir So is it even possible for a property to enforce generic constraints on its value like a function does with its parameters?

Comment: You can enforce constraints, but they need to be known upfront, you can't expect any extra inference for a property. Functions have type parameters that can be inferred, properties don't

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since this is not possible, a practical approach is to use a setter or a factory that enforces the type constraints. E.g.:

```
type Thing<T, A> = {
    a: A,
    b: SomeTypeDependingoOn<A>
};
class Factory<T> {
    public getThing<A, B extends SomeTypeDependingoOn<A>>(a: A, b: B): Thing<T, A>{
        return { a: a, b: b };
    }
}
let thing: Thing<string, any>;
thing = new Factory<string>().getThing(...); // type checking
```